# Converting a matrix to presence absence matrix based on probability values

Tags: r, matrix

In a site (1-4) by species (A-D) matrix, filled by the probability of each species to occur at each site:

```
,A,B,C,D
1,0.9,0.8,0.7,0.6
2,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9
3,0.3,0.55,0.65,0.95
4,0.65,0.6,0.5,0.8
```

- Site 1 has a total of 4 observed species,
- site 2 has 3 observed species,
- site 3 has 2 observed species and
- site 4 has only 1 observed species.

How can I convert the original matrix into a presence/absence (1/0) based on the probability of occurrence values and the observed number of species at each site?

Comment: what are the species observed in each site? These data are missing to solve your problem.

Comment: The matrix is filled with probabilities of occurrence. I want to see if those match my observed data after ranking and ordering the data in this matrix

Comment: I understood but WHAT are your observed data?? You only gave your matrix.

Comment: The data are in the Dropbox file. Follow the link

Comment: sorry but there is only a matrix in your file. What you are asking is completely unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you want to sample N species (without replacement) per site, weighted by the given probabilities ...

```
probs <- read.csv(text="
,A,B,C,D
1,0.9,0.8,0.7,0.6
2,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9
3,0.3,0.55,0.65,0.95
4,0.65,0.6,0.5,0.8")

probs <- probs[,-1] ## drop useless first column
sp_site <- c(4,3,2,1)
nsp <- ncol(probs)
nsite <- nrow(probs)
presabs <- matrix(0,nsp,nsite)
set.seed(101)
for (i in 1:nsite) {
    presabs[i,sample(1:nsp,size=sp_site[i],
                     prob=probs[i,],replace=FALSE)] <- 1
}
presabs
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## [1,]    1    1    1    1
## [2,]    1    0    1    1
## [3,]    0    1    0    1
## [4,]    1    0    0    0
```